# Вывод ошибки переводчика (googletrans) discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def trans (ctx, lang,*, args):
    o = translator.translate(f'{args}', dest = f'{lang}')
    em = discord.Embed(title = 'Переводчик.')
    em.add_field(name = 'Оригинал текста:', value = f'{args}', inline = False)
    em.add_field(name = f'Перевод ({lang}):', value = f'{o.text}', inline = False)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Если язык не был найден, то бот должен отправить ошибку в чат. Как можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@client.command()
async def trans (ctx, lang,*, args):
    try:
        o = translator.translate(f'{args}', dest = f'{lang}')
    except Exception as e:
        # обработка исключения
        em = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка при переводе.')
        em.add_field(name = 'Текст ошибки', value = str(e), inline = False)
    else:
        em = discord.Embed(title = 'Переводчик.')
        em.add_field(name = 'Оригинал текста:', value = f'{args}', inline = False)
        em.add_field(name = f'Перевод ({lang}):', value = f'{o.text}', inline = False)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```